# MATLAB: `vertcat` reversed (2D into 3D)

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I'm looking for an efficient way to split a huge 2D matrix into several blocks and transfer these blocks into the 3rd dimension.

Take `mat_orig` (`100x10`). After every other 20 rows, I need to make a cut and put the resulting block into the 3rd dimension. That is, my `100x10`matrix must result in a `20x10x5` matrix.

My solution involves mat2cell, permute, and cell2mat. It's working, however, I'm working on quite some large matrices. I am wondering if somebody feels challenged and can provide a more sophisticated (faster) solution?

```
mat_orig = reshape(1:1000, 10, 100)';
mat_len = 20;
num_pages = size(mat_orig, 1) / mat_len;

tic;
mat_splitted = cell2mat(permute(mat2cell(mat_orig, ones(1, num_pages) * 
size(mat_orig, 1) / num_pages, 10), [3, 2,1]));
toc (% Elapsed time is 0.108561 seconds.)



mat_orig = reshape(1:100000000, 10, 10000000)';
mat_len = 10000;
num_pages = size(mat_orig, 1) / mat_len;

tic;
mat_splitted = cell2mat(permute(mat2cell(mat_orig, ones(1, num_pages) * 
size(mat_orig, 1) / num_pages, 10), [3, 2,1]));
toc (% Elapsed time is 4.361126 seconds.)
```

Comment: Your `mat_splitted` in this example is `10000*10*1000` - this doesn't match what you say is your expected result. Can you please update your example so that it matches the description? It would be useful if `mat_orig` was actually `100*10` as in your description, this is easier to visualise than the large example you've given... I'd be interested why `reshape( mat_orig, 20, size(mat_orig,2), [] )` doesn't do the job?

Comment: you can ignore most of my comment above, I now realise you gave a short example (per the description) and a big example (to make the timing more effective).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid `cell2mat`:

```
N = 20; % number of rows per block
mat_split = permute(reshape(mat_orig, N, [], size(mat_orig,2)), [1 3 2]);
```